# uipickerView is in the middle of view and change default inputview position

Tags: ipad

I have create an iPad application of data entry.
I use a Tableview for data entry end the cells is custom cell.
For the date I have created a textfield with a pickerview (UIDatePicker)

```
    pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    [pickerView sizeToFit];
    pickerView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

    self.dateField.inputView = pickerView;
```

The problem is that when I press on the textfield, it shows the pickerview in the middel of view and when I press the "Done" button to hide the pickerview the defaul position of the inputview (default keyboard) is not in the bottom of view but in the middle. If press again on the "Done" button of the picker view, the keyboard position increase its x value.

The problem is because when I show the pickerview, the keyboard is undocked (iOS5).

Is it possible to set the undocked - docked state of the keyboard in the code?

I have insert image of my problem:

[Foto default keyboard](http://gandelr.altervista.org/Matteo/foto-1.PNG)

[Foto Pickerview](http://gandelr.altervista.org/Matteo/foto-3.PNG)

Comment: Have you found any soulution?
I have the same problem with custom num-keyboard with undock/split enabled.